# Can't compile Swift package with Kitura on Xcode 8

Tags: swift, kitura

Trying Kitura from IBM. I made swift package using

```
swift package init --type executable
```

then I made xcode proj with

```
swift package generate-xcodeproj
```

My Packages.swift file is like this

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "testSwiftServer",
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura.git", majorVersion: 0, minor: 31)
    ]
)
```

and my main.swift file:

```
import Kitura

let router = Router()

router.get("/") {
    request, response, next in
    response.send("la la la")
    next()
}

Kitura.addHTTPServer(onPort: 8090, with: router)
Kitura.run()
```

I'm using new XCode8. `swift --version` giving me this

```
Apple Swift version 3.0 (swiftlang-800.0.46.2 clang-800.0.38)
```

This works fine when I'm lunching it from command line with `swift build`

But when I'm trying to Run this from XCode I get `error: missing required module 'CCurl'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be working for me. I followed the steps in a slightly different order, but was able to build and then run. I could see the expected `la la la` output in the browser.

- Generate the SPM structure with the `init` command
- Update `Package.swift` with your code above
- Run the `generate-xcodeproj` command to create the Xcode project
- Open the Xcode project
- Updated `main.swift` with your code above
- **New step**: Update scheme to set the Executable (Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme...)
- Run the project
- View http://localhost:8090 in browser

Swift version: `Apple Swift version 3.0 (swiftlang-800.0.46.2 clang-800.0.38)`

Xcode version: `8.0 (8A218a)`

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! Later I tried exactly what I was doing at my home Mac and it works. At work I have Xcode7 and Xcode8 installed simultaneously so probably this what caused my problem.